# EventSystem have no module at runtime in unity_ Input problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

unity 2018.4.11

For example, I want to click a button in a new scene, so I place one. My [canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZwYX.png) have Graphic Raycaster.My [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTq3o.png) is Interactable.My [EventSystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uus0l.png) has a Standalone Input Module. But after I press Play. My button can't be a click, don't change color when I hover it. The [EventSystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8JK0.png) has no information about my input. The black box at right-down has nothing, no module. I have tried resetting my Input in a project setting, re-add EventSystem, re-add standalone Input Module, re-open unity and my computer. All fail.

I create a new unity 2018.4.11 project, and the button can be click. I have a lot of assets in my unity. I don't know if these [asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdV4n.png) cause the problem.

The problem also let my joystick controller can't be detected. It seems my Input System is broken, but I still need this project and these assets, or there is some way I can move these things to a clean project?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So.  Make a test scene, put a button on it, and a test script to log on click.. if that works the input system is not messed up, it could be something is turning off something on the canvas, or, disabling something.. or... but this is the joy of lots of assets

Comment: @BugFinder I tried it before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I export everything and import to a new unity project and solve it, but I still don't know where is my problem with my orginal project.